# Correct way to pass a warning from backend code to Swing UI in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I have a project for which I am building a Swing UI. Parts of the UI will presumably call some methods in backend classes when files are loaded/etc. to get data with which to populate UI fields (I haven't implemented any of this so far, hence the "presumably"). These methods can throw exceptions if the file is invalid, and the UI can catch these exceptions and use the information contained within to display an informative error dialogue. So far, so good.

But I've found a way in which files are technically invalid, but I am still able to load them using a workaround in the backend. I would like to warn the user about such cases, but still load the file using the workaround, as it is a relatively common error appearing in many real files. So is there an accepted good practice way to pass details of a warning from the backend to the frontend, along with the data? Is a callback (in the form of a lambda expression) a reasonable solution to this, or perhaps passing in a class with a field to be modified? Or should a Pair be returned? None of these ways strike me as being particularly "Java-y", and I was wondering if there was already an accepted pattern for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to fire events from the backend, and listen to them on the GUI side. This way, the backend has a way of notifying anyone who is interested about its changes, warnings, exceptions - all without knowing about any GUI at all. The same backend could be even easily used by a Swing GUI and a web frontend simultaneously, and everything would work nicely.

The most basic implementation requires the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) which is the heart of every GUI application.

In practice, though, a much better solution is to use an Event bus. An Event bus is an crossover of [the Mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) implementation and the above mentioned Observer, as it does both. You fire off an event, the mediator catches it, and replays it back to anyone who has previously registered to him. For more information, take a look at the pages linked below as some of them have more details on how an Event bus is a good thing.

There's a couple of implementations out there, e.g. [Guava `EventBus`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/eventbus/package-summary.html) ([wiki pages](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained)), [Square `Otto`](https://github.com/square/otto) ([pages](http://square.github.io/otto/)), [Greenrobot `EventBus`](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) ([pages](http://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/)), [`MBassador`](https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador), or [Vert.x `EventBus`](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html) ([pages](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#event_bus)).

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the tips. I'm used to doing this sort of thing in Qt (with signals and slots), but for whatever reason it never occurred to me that a similar thing would work in this situation. I'm not particularly experienced in GUI creation, especially not in Java, so I wasn't aware of best practice for this sort of thing! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Muzer Well, you placed an excellent question! It's refreshing to see people actually think about things, and then ask the correct question when unsure what to do. Good luck with coding!